# Free MP3 merge for Mac OS X

Tags: mac, conversion, mp3, ipod, audiobook

I need to merge several MP3 tracks into one, I use Mac OS X 10.5. I want to convert all my Harry Potter CDs to my iPod, but not every minute a new track (as it is on the CDs) but chapterwise. Where can I get a free software? Help, please!

(I've already tried:
Jfuse, but after I had merged a few chapters it said I had to buy it; emicsoft VOB Converter for Mac; File Stitcher; but since they all were shareware, for free they would only let me merge 2 files at once (that would take me days) or half of each file which is useless of course; iTunes advanced settings ("join CD tracks") when importing the CDs, but it would let me only join the complete CD, not chapters...)

(Sorry for my English, hope you could understand what I wanted to say)

Comment: I thought you could join selected tracks in iTunes.  I know that I have done that sort of thing in the past.  (iTunes 6 days...)  I thought it was a question of sorting by track number and then checking the box beside the tracks to join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that you said free, but software that I have used to accomplish what you are trying to do, I have used

> [Audiobook Builder](http://www.splasm.com/audiobookbuilder/)

It is rather inexpensive at $9.95 USD for a Single User Licence

---

**UPDATE**

I just found this software that is free (never used it):

> [Audiobook Maker](http://audiobookmaker.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Audiobook Maker worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

[MP3 Trimmer](http://www.deepniner.net/mp3trimmer/) can join multiple MP3 files. Select Join Files from the menu or do Command+J.  Performs the merge pretty quickly.

Comment: doesn't have a 64 bit version for newer mac OSes

Answer (score 0):

I know your question is old now, but I thought I'd answer it anyway for future googlers! I use this brilliant (and free) piece of software.

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/itinfo/jointogether.php

The only rider I would add is that the chapeterise function does not work in newer Mac operating systems - but yours will be fine, I think.

Comment: Can you add a bit more info, maybe a blurb from the site?